# Overlapping items in RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have UI like this:

[image]

I need to overlap rows on each other, but in recycler view it's becoming difficult.

I tried giving negative margins to top but that did not work, how can I achieve this in recycler view?

Comment: post your relevant code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

**your Activity..**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new OverlapDecoration());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(25,this));
  }
}
```

**Use the AdditemDecoration for overlapping**

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

public class OverlapDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

  private final static int vertOverlap = -40;

  @Override
  public void getItemOffsets (Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    final int itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
    if (itemPosition == 0) {
      return; }
    outRect.set(0, vertOverlap, 0, 0);


  }
}
```

**Your Adapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TextViewHolder> {
  private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
  private static final int ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ADD = 1;

  private List<String> labels;
  Context context;

  public TestAdapter(int count, Context context) {
    labels = new ArrayList<String>(count);
    this.context=context;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      labels.add(String.valueOf(i));

    }
  }

  @Override
  public TextViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate( R.layout.item_add, parent, false);
    return new TextViewHolder(view);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final TextViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (position == labels.size()) {
      holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          addItem();
        }
      });
      return;
    }

    if(position%2==0)
    {
      holder.textView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.green_background_back));
    }
    else
    {
      holder.textView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.green_background_back_white));
    }

    final String label = labels.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(label);
    holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeItem(holder.getPosition());
        }
    });
  }

  private void addItem() {
    if (labels.size() >=1){
        int lastItem = Integer.parseInt(labels.get(labels.size() - 1));
        labels.add(String.valueOf(lastItem + 1));
        notifyItemInserted(labels.size() - 1);
    } else {
        labels.add(new String("0"));
        notifyItemInserted(0);
    }

  }

  private void removeItem(int position) {
    labels.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return labels.size() + 1;
  }
}
```

**activity_recycler_view.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/item_margin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

**adapterlayout**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/green_900"
    android:background="@drawable/green_background_back"
    android:padding="30dp"

    android:text="@string/add_item"/>
```

**Drawable for Changing the background of layout**

**green_background_back.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
  <corners android:topRightRadius="25dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"/>
  <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```

**green_background_back_white.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
  <corners android:topRightRadius="25dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"/>
  <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

**Result**

[image]